# How to login into wordpress in both cross-origin (iframe) and same-origin scenario?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, cookies, samesite, cross-site

I use iframes to display contents from a site aaa.com to a bbb.com where users can register and login to download pro documentations.

And now Chrome blocks all cookies without "Samesite=None ; Secure" attributes and users can't no longer register or login from site bbb.com

I tried the plugin [SameSite Cookies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/samesite/) but it breaks the login and register on site aaa.com and didn't change anything for site bbb.com

So my question is : if I'm getting to set all cookies with "SameSite=None ; Secure" attributes, do you think users will be able to login and register in both same-origin (aaa.com) and cross-origin (bbb.com) scenario ?

And if not do you have any other idea how to achieved this (wordpress REST API maybe)?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found [this solution](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/issues/4) for an apache server.

Add this line in the header module section of the .htaccess file.

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=None; Secure
```

That works like a charme for me.

Hope that's help!